# How do I copy a class with a std::vector as a member variable?

Tags: c++

I have made a simple Matrix class with a std::vector as the underlying container.
My problem is when i use the copy constructor on the Matrix class, the std::vector does not get copied.

My matrix.h:

```
#ifndef MATRIX_H
#define MATRIX_H

#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class Matrix
{
private:
    int m_rows;
    int m_cols;
    std::vector<T> m_vector;

public:
    // Constructor
    Matrix(int rows, int cols)
        : m_rows{ rows }, m_cols{ cols }
    { 
        m_vector.reserve(rows * cols);
        std::cout << "Constructor. vector capacity = " << m_vector.capacity() << '\n'; 
    }
    
    // Copy constructor
    Matrix(const Matrix<T>& old)
        : m_rows{ old.m_rows }, m_cols{ old.m_cols }
    {
         m_vector.reserve(old.m_rows * old.m_cols);
         m_vector = old.m_vector;
        std::cout << "Copy constructor. vector capacity = " << m_vector.capacity() << '\n';
    }

    const T& operator()(int row, int col) const
    {
        return m_vector[row * m_cols + col];
    }

    T& operator()(int row, int col)
    {
        return m_vector[row * m_cols + col];
    }
}
```

My test of the class in main.cpp is then:

```
#include "matrix.h"

int main()
{
    // Create new matrix and fill
    Matrix<int> matrix(3, 3);

    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            matrix(i, j) = count++;
        }
    }
    
    // Print new matrix
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            std::cout << matrix(i, j) << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    // Copy assignment and print new
    Matrix<int> matrix2(matrix);


    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            std::cout << matrix2(i, j) << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

I was expecting this to print identical matrices of ints 0-8.
This is the output:

```
Constructor. vector capacity = 9
0 1 2 
3 4 5 
6 7 8 

Copy constructor. vector capacity = 9
0 0 0 
0 0 0 
0 0 0
```

I seems that the copying in the copy constructor doesn't copy the std::vector properly

Comment: It looks like you've overcomplicated it. The copy ctor should probably be `Matrix(const Matrix<T>& old) = default;` - Did you try that?

Comment: Follow the [rule of zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three#Rule_of_zero) and let the compiler generate the copy constructor and the copy assignment operator for you instead. Also, note that `std::vector::reserve` changes only the capacity but not the sizes of the vectors, which is not what you want. Use `std::vector::resize` instead. Alternatively (and it's better), initialize the vector to your desired length in the initializer list.

Comment: `reserve()` does not do what you think it does. That's the bug. Use your debugger, and see for yourself. I did not immediately see the bug myself, but I simply used a debugger and figured it out in ten seconds. You can use this as an opportunity to learn how to use a debugger, which is a mandatory skill for every C++ developer, and then be able to figure out and fix all bugs in your own code, all by yourself, without having to ask anyone for help. Doesn't that make a lot of sense?

Comment: I concur.  Rule of zero is strongly recommended 99% of the time, because, usually, it just 'does the right thing'.  All you need to make sure of is that all non-trivial member variables have proper copy / move constructors / assignment operators (which all the STL containers do, which is one of the reasons why they are so useful).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After this constructor has been used

```cpp
Matrix(int rows, int cols) : m_rows{rows}, m_cols{cols} {
    m_vector.reserve(rows * cols);
}
```

there are exactly zero elements in the `vector` and trying to access elements in the `vector` will have undefined behavior. The proper constructor should actually create the elements instead:

```cpp
Matrix(int rows, int cols) : m_rows{rows}, m_cols{cols}, m_vector(rows * cols) {
}
```

With that in place, you don't even have to add a user-defined copy constructor. The compiler-generated copy and move constructors will do the right thing.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/TKae3nqEx)

Comment: Thanks for both of your comments. It does work now. I initially though the default constructor would be sufficient, but probably due to a typo of mine it didn't work and i overcomplicated it (as i suspected). thx

Answer (score 2):

Neither of your constructors are correct `reserve` merely *reserves* space, it is not yours to work with, `size()` will correctly report `0`.

All STL containers can be copied simply via `Container dest = src;` (assuming the elements are copyable). But in this case you are technically copying an empty vector so the result is empty. The fact you have violated `std::vector` trust by using unchecked `operator[]` is your issue, from the point of `std::vector`, it is not your memory to work with and the container remains empty.

What you want is `resize` in both cases, after that the example will work.

As others have said, use rule of zero - default copy/move ctor/assignments are correct and will be generated for you.